# Pytorch dist.all_gather_object hangs

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, distributed

I'm using dist.all_gather_object (PyTorch version 1.8) to collect sample ids from all GPUs:

```
for batch in dataloader:
    video_sns = batch["video_ids"]
    logits = model(batch)
    group_gather_vdnames = [None for _ in range(envs['nGPU'])]
    group_gather_logits = [torch.zeros_like(logits) for _ in range(envs['nGPU'])]
    dist.all_gather(group_gather_logits, logits)
    dist.all_gather_object(group_gather_vdnames, video_sns)
```

The line `dist.all_gather(group_gather_logits, logits)` works properly,
but program hangs at line `dist.all_gather_object(group_gather_vdnames, video_sns)`.

I wonder why the program hangs at `dist.all_gather_object()`, how can I fix it ?

EXTRA INFO:
I run my ddp code on a local machine with multiple GPUs. The start script is:

```
export NUM_NODES=1
export NUM_GPUS_PER_NODE=2
export NODE_RANK=0
export WORLD_SIZE=$(($NUM_NODES * $NUM_GPUS_PER_NODE))

python -m torch.distributed.launch \
       --nproc_per_node=$NUM_GPUS_PER_NODE \
       --nnodes=$NUM_NODES \
       --node_rank $NODE_RANK \
       main.py \
       --my_args
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out we need to set the device id manually as mentioned in the [docstring](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributed.html#torch.distributed.all_gather_object) of `dist.all_gather_object()` API.

Adding

```
torch.cuda.set_device(envs['LRANK']) # my local gpu_id
```

and the codes work.

I always thought the GPU ID is set automatically by PyTorch dist, turns out it's not.